# I want to implement token based authentication using spring

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm trying to implement token based authentication in my spring project.

I want to use spring-outh2.
my project will work as a outh-provider as well as outh-consumer.
We are creating Rest full services so that we can call it from android also.
I need help to configure outh2 in spring.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [oauth2-provider application](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/1.0.5.RELEASE/samples/oauth2) provided by the Spring Security developers. [This](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/1.0.5.RELEASE/samples/oauth2/sparklr/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml) example configuration contains everything you need.